# How to inject beans in QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager implementations

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I try to implement a QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager implemenation which injects/looks up a bean in ArC, however the bean is not found.

```
public class FlywayTestResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {


    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {

        Flyway flyway = Arc.container().instance(Flyway.class).get(); //fails
...
```

Is it basically possible to get some beans injected or can it not work because at this point quarkus arc is not initialized?

Update:

Looks like `ConfigProvider.getConfig()` does not include application.properties in its sources

[image]

Update2: dirty hack could be copying over application.properties to system properties which is super ugly IMO.
Or is there a less cumbersome way to add application.properties to config sources?

```
public void loadApplicationProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application.properties").getPath();

        try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(path)) {
            properties.load(input);

            for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
                String value = properties.getProperty(key);
                System.setProperty(key, value);
            }

            System.out.println("Properties copied to environment variables successfully.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, CDI is not available in `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` for the very simple reason that the latter is used to creat the environment the former will participate in.

Answer (score 1):

[`Starting services before the Quarkus application starts`](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource) so I suppose CDI context is not still active.
[This extension](https://github.com/radcortez/flyway-junit5-extensions) written by @radcortez is using plain flyway to achive the result; give it a look.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the extension. Unfortunately looks like it is not supporting referring to a named datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Az Luca mentioned CDI context is not fully initialized. That means annotation based injection (using `@Inject`) is not ready at this point, but `Arc.container().instance()` should work.

Here the problem is that class is not a CDI bean. According to javadoc it can be initialized like:

```java
Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(url, user, password).load();
flyway.migrate();
```

As I said before, CDI context is not ready. So reading configuration values using `@ConfigProperty` won't work either.
If you need to access datasource configuration (e.g. url/user/pass) `ConfigProvider.getConfig()` is available.

Under the hood Quarkus using Smallrye Config which follows the [MicroProfile Config](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/) specification.

It works with default datasource confuguration:

```java
var config = ConfigProvider.getConfig();
var url = config.getValue("quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url", String.class);
var username = config.getValue("quarkus.datasource.username", String.class);
var password = config.getValue("quarkus.datasource.password", String.class);


Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(url, username, password).load();
flyway.migrate();
```

Comment: Thanks @zforgo . I just tried that (https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/blob/flyway_test_resource/src/test/java/org/acme/FlywayTestResource.java) but now quarkus is bothering me with `SRCFG00014: The config property quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url is required but it could not be found in any config source`

Even though, `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` is defined in main and test.
Happens both in maven build or test run from intellij :/

Comment: @syr `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` is not defined in your `application.properties`

Comment: yes it is here 
https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/blob/flyway_test_resource/src/test/resources/application.properties

and here 

https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/blob/flyway_test_resource/src/main/resources/application.properties

Please also check my update (screenshot). `ConfigProvider.getConfig()` seems not to have application.properties in its sources.

Comment: Sorry I pulled the default branch. I'll take a look.

Comment: No worries, thanks for checking ;)  I added update 2 to my post, which is a working but ugly workaround